# Array jobs using R scripts

Tags: r, job-scheduling, snow

I have an R script which I currently use on our linux HPC as an interactive session.

The script itself does a test based on a set/list of items, and runs 10,000 permutations of the test using snow to create a cluster to parrelelise the permuations (To run it I log onto a whole node and use all the processors available to me) i.e:

> ```
> cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost",10), type = "SOCK")
> shortlist <-longlist[1]
> test.result <- test(cl=cl, data=data, items=shortlist, permutations=10000)
> ```

For each of the items in the list, the test with the permutations takes ~3hours. I have ~1500 items to run so I would like to either:

-Make a script that can generate lots of R my scripts, numbered sequentially and each drawing on 1-2 items, that can each be be submitted singly, using an array job wrapper.

-Or something cleverer that means I dont have to generate 750-1500 R scripts but results in the same.

So I know how to submit an R script in a BASH script, but I don't know how to put in a way to iterate through the list within the R script. Possibly it's really easy which might be why I cant find something relevant (or I am using the wrong terminology?) any pointers welcome.

Comment: If you want to generate scripts in R, you could look into `writeLines`, working from some template to make a bunch of nearly identical files. A probably more efficient approach is to create a script that accepts command line arguments, which you can incorporate into the script using `commandArgs`, so that you don't have to generate hundreds of scripts. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Great! commandArgs looks relevant I will look into it, thank you.